# "Test Failed: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'"

Tags: python, ping, icmp

i keep having a problem in my code coming back as Test Failed: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'.

i am a super beginner who is not very good at coding, so i cannot figure out what the issue is.

here is the full code.

i am making a simple icmp pinger program.

thanks everyone for your help!!!
(this is my first question here so please let me know if i need to edit anything)

```
from socket import *
import os
import sys
import struct
import time
import select
import statistics
import binascii

# Should use stdev

ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST = 8


def checksum(string):
   csum = 0
   countTo = (len(string) // 2) * 2
   count = 0

   while count < countTo:
       thisVal = (string[count + 1]) * 256 + (string[count])
       csum += thisVal
       csum &= 0xffffffff
       count += 2

   if countTo < len(string):
       csum += (string[len(string) - 1])
       csum &= 0xffffffff

   csum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0xffff)
   csum = csum + (csum >> 16)
   answer = ~csum
   answer = answer & 0xffff
   answer = answer >> 8 | (answer << 8 & 0xff00)
   return answer



def receiveOnePing(mySocket, ID, timeout, destAddr):
   timeLeft = timeout

   while 1:
       startedSelect = time.time()
       whatReady = select.select([mySocket], [], [], timeLeft)
       howLongInSelect = (time.time() - startedSelect)
       if whatReady[0] == []:  # Timeout
           return "Request timed out."

       timeReceived = time.time()
       recPacket, addr = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)

       # Fetch the ICMP header from the IP packet

       header = recPacket[20:28]
       type, code, checksum, packID, seqNo = struct.unpack("bbHHh", header)
       if type == 0 and packID == ID:
          bytesInDouble = struct.calcsize("d")
          timeSent = struct.unpack("d", recPacket[28:28 + bytesInDouble])[0]
          ttls = struct.unpack("c", recPacket[8:9])[0]  
          rtt = timeReceived - timeSent
          return (rtt, ttls)

       timeLeft = timeLeft - howLongInSelect
       if timeLeft <= 0:
           return "Request timed out."


def sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, ID):
   # Header is type (8), code (8), checksum (16), id (16), sequence (16)

   myChecksum = 0
   # Make a dummy header with a 0 checksum
   # struct -- Interpret strings as packed binary data
   header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
   data = struct.pack("d", time.time())
   # Calculate the checksum on the data and the dummy header.
   myChecksum = checksum(header + data)

   # Get the right checksum, and put in the header

   if sys.platform == 'darwin':
       # Convert 16-bit integers from host to network  byte order
       myChecksum = htons(myChecksum) & 0xffff
   else:
       myChecksum = htons(myChecksum)


   header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
   packet = header + data

   mySocket.sendto(packet, (destAddr, 1))  # AF_INET address must be tuple, not str


   # Both LISTS and TUPLES consist of a number of objects
   # which can be referenced by their position number within the object.

def doOnePing(destAddr, timeout):
   icmp = getprotobyname("icmp")


   # SOCK_RAW is a powerful socket type. For more details:   http://sockraw.org/papers/sock_raw
   mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, icmp)

   myID = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF  # Return the current process i
   sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, myID)
   delay = receiveOnePing(mySocket, myID, timeout, destAddr)
   mySocket.close()
   return delay


def ping(host, timeout=1):
  # timeout=1 means: If one second goes by without a reply from the server,      # the client assumes that either the client's ping or the server's pong is lost
   dest = gethostbyname(host)
  # print("Pinging " + dest + " using Python:")
  # print("")
  # Calculate vars values and return them
   count = 0
   val = []
  # Send ping requests to a server separated by approximately one second
   for i in range(0,4):
       delay = doOnePing(dest, timeout)
       val.append(delay)
      # print(delay)
       time.sleep(1)  # one second
         
   if len(val) > 0:      
       packet_min = min(val) * 1000
       packet_avg = sum(val) / len(val) * 1000
       packet_max = max(val) * 1000
       stdev_var =  list(val) * 1000
       vars = [str(round(packet_min, 2)), str(round(packet_avg, 2)), str(round(packet_max, 2)),str(round(stdev(stdev_var), 2))]
   else:
        vars = ['0', '0.0', '0', '0.0']
   return vars

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ping("google.co.il")
```

Comment: Please post a [mre], including the full traceback.

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment! i went ahead and posted the full code. (its homework, so all the #ed out parts are from the professor)

Comment: By traceback I meant the error message. It should say where in the code the error happened.

Comment: unfortunately it was tested on an autograder, and it didn't flag where the error was. the only message info i got was [test_ping_1 (test_simple.Test) (0.0/100.0)
Test Failed: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple']. i'm sorry for the lack of info!

Comment: Run it locally then?

Comment: that's the smartest idea i've heard all day haha. i think my brain is fried. ran it, got this traceback: line 125, in ping
    packet_avg = sum(val) / len(val) * 1000
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

Comment: you seem to have an issue with your checksum, trying to add `int` and `str` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `return (rtt, ttls)` in function `receiveOnePing` and then you return the same tuple from function `doOnePing`. After that, you append this tuple to list and are trying to `sum`  this list of tuples. This leads to the error you mentioned.
You need `val.append(delay[0])` in `ping` function (line 122).

You also use undefined function `stdev`. Should be `statistics.stdev`.

Please note that your script will crash in case of timeout because you return a string in this.
Also the code is runnable only by root.

**UPD**
Below is fixed code.

```
rom socket import *
import os
import sys
import struct
import time
import select
import statistics
import binascii

# Should use stdev

ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST = 8


def checksum(string):
   csum = 0
   countTo = (len(string) // 2) * 2
   count = 0

   while count < countTo:
       thisVal = (string[count + 1]) * 256 + (string[count])
       csum += thisVal
       csum &= 0xffffffff
       count += 2

   if countTo < len(string):
       csum += (string[len(string) - 1])
       csum &= 0xffffffff

   csum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0xffff)
   csum = csum + (csum >> 16)
   answer = ~csum
   answer = answer & 0xffff
   answer = answer >> 8 | (answer << 8 & 0xff00)
   return answer



def receiveOnePing(mySocket, ID, timeout, destAddr):
   timeLeft = timeout

   while 1:
       startedSelect = time.time()
       whatReady = select.select([mySocket], [], [], timeLeft)
       howLongInSelect = (time.time() - startedSelect)
       if whatReady[0] == []:  # Timeout
           return "Request timed out."

       timeReceived = time.time()
       recPacket, addr = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)

       # Fetch the ICMP header from the IP packet

       header = recPacket[20:28]
       type, code, checksum, packID, seqNo = struct.unpack("bbHHh", header)
       if type == 0 and packID == ID:
          bytesInDouble = struct.calcsize("d")
          timeSent = struct.unpack("d", recPacket[28:28 + bytesInDouble])[0]
          ttls = struct.unpack("c", recPacket[8:9])[0]  
          rtt = timeReceived - timeSent
          return (rtt, ttls)

       timeLeft = timeLeft - howLongInSelect
       if timeLeft <= 0:
           return "Request timed out."


def sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, ID):
   # Header is type (8), code (8), checksum (16), id (16), sequence (16)

   myChecksum = 0
   # Make a dummy header with a 0 checksum
   # struct -- Interpret strings as packed binary data
   header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
   data = struct.pack("d", time.time())
   # Calculate the checksum on the data and the dummy header.
   myChecksum = checksum(header + data)

   # Get the right checksum, and put in the header

   if sys.platform == 'darwin':
       # Convert 16-bit integers from host to network  byte order
       myChecksum = htons(myChecksum) & 0xffff
   else:
       myChecksum = htons(myChecksum)


   header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
   packet = header + data

   mySocket.sendto(packet, (destAddr, 1))  # AF_INET address must be tuple, not str


   # Both LISTS and TUPLES consist of a number of objects
   # which can be referenced by their position number within the object.

def doOnePing(destAddr, timeout):
   icmp = getprotobyname("icmp")


   # SOCK_RAW is a powerful socket type. For more details:   http://sockraw.org/papers/sock_raw
   mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, icmp)

   myID = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF  # Return the current process i
   sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, myID)
   delay = receiveOnePing(mySocket, myID, timeout, destAddr)
   mySocket.close()
   return delay


def ping(host, timeout=1):
  # timeout=1 means: If one second goes by without a reply from the server,      # the client assumes that either the client's ping or the server's pong is lost
   dest = gethostbyname(host)
  # print("Pinging " + dest + " using Python:")
  # print("")
  # Calculate vars values and return them
   count = 0
   val = []
  # Send ping requests to a server separated by approximately one second
   for i in range(0,4):
       delay = doOnePing(dest, timeout)
       val.append(delay[0])
      # print(delay)
       time.sleep(1)  # one second
         
   print(val)
   if len(val) > 0:      
       packet_min = min(val) * 1000
       packet_avg = sum(val) / len(val) * 1000
       packet_max = max(val) * 1000
       stdev_var =  list(val) * 1000
       vars = [str(round(packet_min, 2)), str(round(packet_avg, 2)), str(round(packet_max, 2)),str(round(statistics.stdev(stdev_var), 2))]
   else:
        vars = ['0', '0.0', '0', '0.0']
   return vars

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ping("google.co.il")

>sudo python3 ping.py
[0.0778355598449707, 0.07866811752319336, 0.07798004150390625, 0.07628297805786133]
```

Comment: i made the changes you suggested and got the result "Test Failed: 'float' object is not subscriptable." i'm a little confused about the repeat tuples, though, should i take something out? thank you so much!!

Comment: I can update the answer with the changes I made. And it prints a list of floats.

Comment: thank you so so so much. i got it now!! i really appreciate your help and time. thanks again, im so relieved!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in this line:

```
packet_avg = sum(val) / len(val) * 1000
```

Therefore `val` is suspect. Follow the logic back through `doOnePing` to `receiveOnePing` and you will find that function does not return suitable types.

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit? i'm sorry to say that think im too incompetent to figure out what you're telling me exactly...

Comment: `receiveOnePing` returns a tuple, which gets put into the `val` array. That's probably not what you want

Comment: What is worse: it returns a tuple on one path, and a string on other paths.

Comment: thank you both so much. i think i can fix it now! (i hope, haha!!) let me give it another try!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues. What I can see:

you are trying to checksum but in python, using an index returns a string, not a character, so this generates a string, not a number:

```
thisVal = (string[count + 1]) * 256 + (string[count])
```

What you probably want in this case is:

```
thisVal = ord(string[count + 1]) * 256 + ord(string[count])
```

and also on this line:

```
       csum += (string[len(string) - 1])
```

to

```
       csum += ord(string[len(string) - 1])
```

Then, you are putting tuples and possibly strings into your `val` array.
You need to decide how you want to handle the errors/time out of the ping.
You could just ignore them for now:

```
   for i in range(0,4):
       delay = doOnePing(dest, timeout)
       if isinstance(delay, tuple):
           val.append(delay[0])
       time.sleep(1)  # one second
```

That will only add if you received a tuple, and only add the first member of the tuple, which appears to be the delay you want.